# Is the following quotient group isomorphic to a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

Suppose $G$ is a compact connected Lie group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Then is $G/H$ isomorphic to some subgroup of $G$?

Browsing around the internet, I came across the following link: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_group_need_not_be_isomorphic_to_any_subgroup

Here it is stated that

1) If $G$ is a finite abelian group, then any quotient group is isomorphic to some subgroup.

2)  If we quotient the Quarternion group $G$ by its center $H$, this is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $G$.

Can anything be said in my setting above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The group ${\rm Spin}(n)$ is connected and is the universal cover of $SO(n)$ if $n>2$ it is simply connected. ${\rm Spin}(n), n>2$ does not have a subgroup isomorphic to $SO(n)$ since such a subgroup would have been open (dimension) closed (as a Lie subgroup) and equal to ${\rm Spin}(n)$ since ${\rm Spin}(n)$ is connected contradiction since $SO(n)$ is not ${\rm Spin}(n), n>2$ since $SO(n)$ is not simply connected.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group

Comment: What does "open (dimension) closed" mean?

Comment: $dim(SO(n))=dim(Spin(n))$ and if $H\subset Spin(n)$ is isomorphic to $SO(n)$, $dim(H)=dim(Spin(n))$ implies that $H$ is an open subgroup since a submanifold of the same dimension is open . If it is open it is a submanifold and a Lie subgroup, a Lie subgroup is closed.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your reasoning, but the words in your answer are too terse to make sense.